# Recording call never end

Tags: android, call, record

in this time i got u a diferent problem, I have an app to Recording Call, but the recorder.start() never end.
Here is the code for recording:

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
```

this part of code execute when press the a button to call a number. But, when I press endcall button in the AVD this code never run:

```
        phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                switch (state) 
                {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_IDLE";
                    break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK";
                    break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_RINGING";
                    break;
                }

                _fileTrace.onTrace("INFO", "CallState: ", currentPhoneState, null);
                if (currentPhoneState == "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK")
                {                       
                    llamada = true;
                    _fileTrace.onTrace("INFO", "Recording Start", currentPhoneState, null);
                    try {
                        recorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (llamada && currentPhoneState == "CALL_STATE_IDLE") {
                    _fileTrace.onTrace("INFO", "CallState: ", currentPhoneState, null);
                    recorder.stop();
                }                   
            }
        };      
        _CurrTelephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

FYI: the 1st piece of code is in a helper class and the 2nd is in the activity.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks to all!

Comment: last chance to this post guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use following code and its worked:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(context, "calling now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        return;
    else {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            log.d(TAG, "RINGING NOW")

            return;
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            StartRecording();
            Log.d(TAG, "CALL ANSWERED NOW");
            return;
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ALL DONE IN ELSE IF...... !!");
            StopRecording();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ALL DONE IN ELSE ...... !!");

        }
    }
}
```